# How is time reported on HTML5 MediaSource Extension 'updateend' event?

Tags: javascript, html, media-source

I am working with HTML5 VideoSource extensions and I need to know how the time is reported on the ['updateend'](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#dom-evt-updateend) event. When I log the event to the Chrome console I get the following data:

[image]

As shown in the screenshot there is a timeStamp value reported as  ***timeStamp***. I am currently unable to make heads or tails of it and need to know is it milliseconds, microseconds or nanoseconds?. Also how can I convert it into seconds so that I can compare the time that the videoplayer is playing to the time that the event was fired?.

Comment: I don't get exactly why you want to use this `timeStamp` property. I'm not sure it's really reliable to anything. (Chrome uses `performance.now()` since v49, while others are still on an epoch base). Why don't you just call `performance.now()` in your callback, or even just check `Event.target.currentTime` ?

Answer (score 1):

For almost all native event listener (including `updateend` event), `Event.timeStamp` returns the time (in milliseconds) at which the event was created (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp)).

To convert it to seconds use

```
event.timeStamp / 1E3 | 0;
```

If you don't want to truncate it, just remove `| 0`.

**Edit**

Note that starting with Chrome 49, `Event.timeStamp` returns a high-resolution monotonic time instead of epoch time.